# removefromparent in SpriteKit causes other nodes to "lose" properties

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I'm working on a game in SpriteKit.

My main sprite nodes are defined like this:

```
  ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"green"];
  ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:ball.frame.size];
  ballcoordinates = CGPointMake(x, y);
  ball.position = ballcoordinates;
  ball.name = @"green";
  [self addChild:ball];
```

I have other ball Sprites with .name strings "blue,red,yellow...". They are added multiple times & arranged in a 2d grid.

Basically what my code does is:

1. Use touchesBegan to select a ball Sprite:

   ```
   -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:[touch locationInNode:self]];
   }
   ```
2. Select surrounding nodes from coordinates of surrounding (above,below,left,right) nodes using nodeAtPoint. So for the node on the right it looks like:

   ```
   CGPoint right= CGPointMake(touchedNode.position.x + 63, touchedNode.position.y);
   SKNode *rightNode = [ball.parent nodeAtPoint:right];
   ```
3. If the touched string name is equal to any surrounding node's string name, all nodes with the same name are A.) Added to an array B.)Deleted after all surrounding nodes are checked

   ```
   NSMutableArray* ballArray;
   [ballArray addObject:rightNode];
   //Repeated for up,down,left

   for (id ball in ballArray) {
   [ball removeFromParent];
   }
   ```

It works flawlessly 75% of the time. The other 25%, it works until the nodes are removed from the parent. Afterwards if I tap another area of my grid, my  .name string returns the right name for the tapped node, but null for the surrounding nodes. So either my way of selecting the node from nodeAtPoint is wrong, or removeFromParent is deleting a property.

I've spent tons of time on this and still am stumped. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

have you considered that after removeFromParent the nodes are gone (deallocated)? The ballArray itself will not retain the until the method in 3. ends, and in particular it will not retain any node to begin with because assuming above code fragment is all you have, the ballArray is simply nil - you have not allocated an instance of NSMutableArray.

Change it to:

```
NSMutableArray* ballArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

and probably move the declaration to the @interface too, so that the array becomes an ivar rather than being a local var that is released at the end of the method.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I did allocate it before. I'll edit my question. I know it gets deallocated, but that shouldn't matter if I want to delete all nodes in the array? All nodes I add should get deleted. That shouldn't affect the nodes that were not added.

Comment: Also tried a different method where I reassigned a name i.e. "marked" to each node I want to delete. Then I used enumerateChildNodesWithName@"marked" and removed from parent. Again, it worked ~ 3/4 times. It's confusing because

    touchedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:[touch locationInNode:self]];

still shows the right names after deletion.